# Question about image and pre-image of subsets

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Let $M$ and $N$ be sets and $f:M\to N$ be a map. Let $A\subset M$ and $B \subset N$. Show that
$$f(f^{-1}(B)\cap A)=B\cap f(A)$$
As $f^{-1}(B), A\subset M$ we can say that $f(f^{-1}(B)\cap A)\subset f(f^{-1}(B))\cap f(A)$. However, I am unsure as to how to proceed from here. Any help is appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: It is easier to take a point in either side and show that it belongs to the other side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f(x) \in B\cap f(A)$ $\Rightarrow$ $f(x) \in B \land f(x)\in f(A)$

$f(x) \in f(A)$ $\Rightarrow$ $x \in A$

$f(x) \in B$ $\Rightarrow$ $x \in f^{-1}(B)$

$x \in  f^{-1}(B)\cap A$ $\Rightarrow$ $f(x) \in f(f^{-1}(B)\cap A)$

$f(x) \in f(f^{-1}(B)\cap A)$ $\Rightarrow$ $x \in f^{-1}(B)\cap A$

$x \in f^{-1}(B)\cap A$ $\Rightarrow$ $x \in f^{-1}(B) \land A $

$x \in f^{-1}(B)$ $\Rightarrow$ $f(x) \in B$ , $x \in A$  $\Rightarrow$ $f(x) \in f(A)$

$f(x) \in B\cap f(A)$

$f(f^{-1}(B)\cap A)=B\cap f(A)$